# Url share to Facebook -> dont show Image

Tags: image, facebook, sharing

could you tell me why when I Share this url on Facebook :

https://www.quoi-faire.fr/event/l-opera-de-quat-sous-27100-val-de-reuil-26-04-2017-26-04-2017

Facebook thow me the thumbnail

And when I am sharing this Url not :

https://www.quoi-faire.fr/event/musique-vincent-delerm-27000-evreux-27-04-2017-27-04-2017

Thank you

Comment: Probably just a caching issue. I put your second URL through https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ once, and now the image shows up.

Comment: Thank you It was a caching issue !! I do not know why I did not think about it earlier

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your tags are set up. Here is an example of what should be on the page.

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="[URL]" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="[Type]" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="[Title]" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="[Descritption]" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="[img url]" />
```

Those are the meta tags that Facebook looks for.